# Azure synapse Dedicated SQL Pools - Getting table "index hints" working

Tags: azure-sql-database, query-optimization, azure-synapse

Q: **How do you put table query hints in sql pools?  They don't seem to be recognised?**

We have a synapse dedicated sql pool with multiple tables which we join in our queries and functions.

The schema has been optimised in that the joining most of the tables aligns with the hash distribution.  For this reason simple queries are really quite fast as most joining is done on the individual nodes.

Unfortunately, some sql queries are causing the query optimiser to malfunction, join in the incorrect way, causing a near 10 times decrease in speed.

We have tried multiple ways to specify which joining index to use using various "hints"
e.g. with (index = XXXX) and with (index(XXXXX)) and option(...), however the dedicated sql pools does not seem to recognise any table query hints and returns errors.

If we don't fix this, then dedicated sql pools is pretty much unsuitable for our business domains.
(It is also strange there isn't actual up to date documentation around on this - sql pools does not even nearly implement the t-sql specification it would seem so it is odd that documentation doesn't seem to exist for the actual implementation?)

Any help to get index hints working greatly appreciated!

Edit - some background information - though keep in mind - we're after info on how to get HINTS working:

In short - we have 2 main tables - one which holds daily sourced information, and one which is a multi-day properties lookup.

The base query is along the lines of:

```
select d.*, mp.* from Daily d
inner join MultiDayProperties mp on (mp.id = d.propertyid)
where d.reportDate = '20210914' and....
```

Both tables are hash distributed on mp.id and d.propertyid, with an additional table indices on d.reportDate and mp.id.

Normally what occurs is that the Daily table is queried for reportDate, and the Daily entries are joined with their MultiDayProperties table lookup - this turns out to be very fast as both entries are in the same node.

However, when restricting the query further on  MultiDayProperties,
e.g "and mp.param1='abc' and mp.param2='cde'",
then we are in effect getting a table scan on the (huge) MultiDayProperties table, with the resultant  superset ids then broadcast joined with the Daily table.  (10x slower)

This sort of situation I've solved with normal SQL Server using appropriate query hints, however I have not been able to do this with Synapse SQL Pools.

**In short - I am just after help with SQL POOLS table query hints :

SqlServer allows table query hints - how is it possible to use such table query hints with SQL POOLS?**

Comment: Do you have an example query that isn’t performing as expected? What’s the distribution for all tables involved? Can you put EXPLAIN in front of the query and include the explain plan for the query?

Comment: Hi - updated the question with more information thanks

Comment: are the tables columnstore or clustered index or heap? Is auto create stats on? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-statistics#automatic-creation-of-statistics

Comment: Stats are on, and we auto update them every morning.
The problem I'm asking for help for here is how to use table query HINTS (like in normal sql server) on SQL POOLS - as they do not seem to be supported?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so - after trying a number of things, found that in the cases going wrong, adding the following at the end of the query fixed the issue:

OPTION (USE HINT ( 'ASSUME_MIN_SELECTIVITY_FOR_FILTER_ESTIMATES' ));

This stopped the ShuffleMoveOperation storm in the cases that were going wrong.

Hints:
ASSUME_JOIN_PREDICATE_DEPENDS_ON_FILTERS &  ASSUME_FULL_INDEPENDENCE_FOR_FILTER_ESTIMATES also seemed to help (though less than MIN_SELECTIVITY)